# How to build a toggle on/off chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm completely new in building chrome extensions. I've tried a building a couple extensions that work when i click on them. This time i've been trying to figure out how to build a toggle on/off extensions.

Basically what i'm trying to build is an extension that executes a code (ex: alert('Hi')) when i toggle it on and off and will continue to run on every page until i toggle it off.

I've looked a lot and I can't find any good resources that could explain how to do it.
i have my manifest and my html file and i know i need a popup.js and background.js files but i have no idea what to put inside.

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Toggle Extension",
  "description": "My Personal Toggle Extension",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "icons": {
    "128": "img/icon_128.png"
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["js/background.js"]
  }
}
```

popup.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>POC Extension</title>
  <meta name="description" content="POC Extension">
  <meta name="author" content="Yann Bohbot">
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/popup.css"> -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/popup.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Toggle</h2>
  <ul class="tg-list">
    <li class="tg-list-item">
      <h4>Flat</h4>
      <input type="checkbox" id="cb4" class="tgl tgl-flat" value = "Disable" />
      <label class="tgl-btn" for="cb4"></label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

> an extension that executes a code (ex: alert('Hi')) when i toggle it
>   on and off and will continue to run on every page until i toggle it
>   off.

Seems like you have to read a lot on this resourse: [google extension guide](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage)
I would have done this task in this way:

1. popup.html have popup.js file, which have a function which sends
   state of your extension ("ON" or "OFF") to background script;
2. content.js runs on each tab in browser, and it starts with request
   to background script whether your extension is ON or OFF;
3. background script sends a respond to each content script with
   current state of your ext.
4. when content script get the respond,
   it checks it and decides shoud it stop or continue execution of your
   script.

So, it is obvious that at first you need a content script. Put this snippet in you manifest file:

```js
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "js":         [ "content.js" ],
    "matches":    [ "<all_urls>" ],
    "all_frames": true,
    "run_at":     "document_end"
  }
],
```

At the beginning of your **content.js** file write:

```js
console.log("Hello, Yann!");

chrome.runtime.sendMessage( {myQuestion: "Is it ON or OFF?"}, function(response) {
  console.log( "Extension state is: " + response.state); // should be ON
  if(response.state !== "ON") return;

  // Put the code you want to execute on every tab below:
  // ....
});
```

Your **background.js** file must have this piece of code:

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log( "Your question was: "  + request.myQuestion );

    // here we will get information whether ext is ON or OFF from the popup;

    sendResponse({state: "I don't know, but I'll find it out!"});
  });
```

Try this, if it works, I'll try to help with popup.

Comment: Of note: you can completely get rid of background page as a message router if `chrome.storage` is used instead; it's directly accessible from the content script.

Comment: great! let me try this out and reach back :)

Comment: Xan - indeed. I did similar task with background page because of lots of involved async subtasks. Of course, this particular check should be done with chrome.storage.